# BOOL variable returning NULL in Singleton

Tags: design-patterns, ios7, singleton

I dont normlly have issues with this.

I just moved back over to Objective-C and its giving me a headache.

My singleton .h

```
@interface BFTDataHandler : NSObject

+ (BFTDataHandler *)sharedInstance;

@property BOOL *initialLogin;
@property BOOL *PPAccepted;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *Username;
@property(assign) NSString *EDEmail;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *UID;
@property(assign) NSString *Longitude;
@property(assign) NSString *Latitude;

@end
```

My Singleton .m

```
#import "BFTDataHandler.h"

@implementation BFTDataHandler

-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
 //initlize data
    _Username = nil;
    _EDEmail = nil;
    _UID = nil;
    _Longitude = nil;
    _Latitude = nil;
    _initialLogin = false;
    _PPAccepted = false;
}
return self;
}

+ (BFTDataHandler *)sharedInstance
{
static BFTDataHandler *_sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceSecurePredicate;
dispatch_once(&onceSecurePredicate,^
              {
                  _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
              });
return _sharedInstance;
}
```

I will try and access the PPAccepted BOOL and it keeps returning NULL

```
NSLog(@"%s", [[BFTDataHandler sharedInstance] PPAccepted]);
return *[[BFTDataHandler sharedInstance]PPAccepted];
```

I cant figure out the issue, thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `@property BOOL *initialLogin;`

While it's certainly possible to create a property that's a pointer to a `BOOL`, in this case it looks like you meant to declare it as a `BOOL` instead of a `BOOL*`. Try changing your code thus:

```
@property BOOL initialLogin;  // note that the '*' has been removed
@property BOOL PPAccepted;
```

`BOOL` is a scalar type, not a class, so you don't need to refer to a `BOOL` with a pointer.

Comment: Thank you so much....sometimes its the late nights that make it hard to remember the simplest things haha